# How to switch to source mode when doing 'next' in gdb site:stackoverflow.com

Tags: debugging, gdb, gdbinit

I build a program with '-g', if I use this [gdbinit](https://github.com/chenkaie/DotFiles/blob/master/.gdbinit-7.3), I type `next` will step to next instruction instead of step next line.

I don't know what changed in that init file. Any advise?

Comment: Do you get some warning or error message?

Comment: @ssbssa no warning or error